# Power BI DAX: Find total amount of bookmarks from only top 10 users?

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, slicers

This is the current data table that I have, which is called 'Bookmark Information'.
[image: Click to see table]
I need to do 2 things:

1. Create a measure to find the total count of bookmarks per each bookmark title, but only from the rows that are the top 10 highest numbers in the column "Number of submission breaktie column".
2. Since I will later on add a date slicer, it should also only show me the top 10 highest numbers in the column "Number of submission breaktie column" per the date range in the slicer and the corresponding total count of bookmarks per each bookmark title.

I have tried something like this, but it is not giving me the correct number:

```
Sum of Bookmarks = SUM(Bookmark Information [Count of Bookmark])
Top 10 total bookmarks = CALCULATE([Sum of Bookmarks], TopN(10,'Bookmark Information','Bookmark Information'[Number of Submission breaktie column],DESC))
```

Comment: Add sample dummy data in tabular form (An example that can be reproduced.), Add also your desired output. Currently, we don't know what output do you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this `= sumx(values[tablecolumn]), if(measure) > 0, 1, blank())`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Top N in Advanced filtering on "Filters on this visual" to get the result

[image]

You can add Date slicer up on it.